# How to fix permissions after Sudo chown root -R /usr

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-14.04, sudo

How do you fix the permissions in /usr after `sudo chown root -R /usr`?

I managed to fix sudo using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491211/sudo-error-setuid) but how should I fix the rest?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102806/how-to-recover-from-chown-r-user-usr

Comment: `sudo chown root -R /usr` will just change ownership of all files and dir to user root. There will be a few that will need to run as other users or provide other access (gladly only a few). Were it I, I would just wait for the first error to pop into the log, read and then go change files associated set of files say apace back to `apache` or `http`, etc. If you have a distro with a config that check that stuff, like `suseconfig`, you may be able to run that to get a list of all the files you will need to address. If you run `bind` those will be others. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most files on `/usr` are owned by `root`, so it should have not changed many files.

As you says that `sudo` has lost its `setuid` bit, all commands on `/usr/` that had it must have lost it too. You will probably notice it when you try to run them, so you can add it to them again.

Edit:

I'm giving you some info about `/usr` on my personal machine that may help you to recover. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

On my machine, all files under `/usr` are owned by `root`, except `/usr/sbin/uuidd`, which is owned by `libuuid` (and `setuid` to that user):

```
-rwsr-sr-x 1 libuuid libuuid 18904 ago  5 04:20 /usr/sbin/uuidd*
```

I also have the following files `setuid`, all by `root`, except the one I told you above:

```
/usr/sbin/uuidd
/usr/sbin/pppd
/usr/bin/passwd
/usr/bin/lppasswd
/usr/bin/sudo
/usr/bin/chsh
/usr/bin/newgrp
/usr/bin/traceroute6.iputils
/usr/bin/beep
/usr/bin/X
/usr/bin/chfn
/usr/bin/pkexec
/usr/bin/mtr
/usr/bin/gpasswd
/usr/lib/openssh/ssh-keysign
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome-sandbox
/usr/lib/eject/dmcrypt-get-device
/usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
/usr/lib/pt_chown
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/oxide-qt/chrome-sandbox
```